# Vanity Mining Error?

Tags: vanity-address, vanitygen

Well after getting a new graphics card (7770) I can mine bitcoins at around 120 - 180 Mhash/s Depending if I run it at full power or not.

Now I thought I would try and mine myself an address using it but the miner just seems to not work.

Using Vanitygen (Linked below) oclvanitygen I set it off mining with reports of it mining at around 4MKeys/s but nothing was showing up after 5 mins worth of time(I tried a simple prefix of 1r).

I then tried using just vanitygen64 and in seconds it found an address.

Does anyone know why?

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=25804.0

Comment: Is it possible to get / post debug logs?  Perhaps OpenCL isn't installed /working correctly with your card.

Comment: The application starts and runs fine but then produces no keys, it don't error out at all.
Running it in safe mode generates the key but is lots slower.

http://pastebin.com/tYPnpJnn Is output with the -v flag

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add two lines to `oclengine.c`:

```
vg_ocl_device_getstr(vocp->voc_ocldid,
                           CL_DEVICE_NAME);
                           CL_DEVICE_NAME);
+           if (!strcmp(dvn, "Tahiti") || !strcmp(dvn, "Barts") || !strcmp(dvn, "Pitcairn"))
+               quirks &= ~VG_OCL_AMD_BFI_INT;
            if (!strcmp(dvn, "ATI RV710")) {
            if (!strcmp(dvn, "ATI RV710")) {
                quirks &= ~VG_OCL_OPTIMIZATIONS;
                quirks &= ~VG_OCL_OPTIMIZATIONS;
                quirks |= VG_OCL_NO_BINARIES;
                quirks |= VG_OCL_NO_BINARIES;
```

Add the lines starting with `+`, but don't copy the plus sign.

This code adds optimizations for AMD HD 68XX, 69XX, 7XXX

Thanks to Kevin Pan for [his patch](https://github.com/samr7/vanitygen/pull/53)!